# How to follow redirect from 404 with Jsoup

Tags: java, http, jsoup

I want to scrape the redirected tumblr site which comes up if you try to go to a tumblr page that doesnt exist. If I put the URL in the browser I get to that redirected site. Jsoup however just gives back a " HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404" Error. Any suggestions?

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.faszokvagyunk.tumblr.com").userAgent(userAgent).followRedirects(true).get();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seem to handle other types of redirects just fine however, with tumblr  you get a 404 page that causes a 404 status hence, the exception and there could be many reasons to this:

- Redirect might not happen at all
- Tumblr does redirect in a strange way
- Tumblr unnecessary returns 404 which causes the exception
- Other possibilities

I don't know if this solution can help you but, you actually can instruct your JSOUP connection to ignoreHttpErrors by chaining the method as follow (this at least allow you to validate the http errors):

```
Document doc =  Jsoup.connect("http://oddhouredproductivity.tumblr.com/tagged/tips").userAgent(userAgent).followRedirects(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
```

**ignoreHttpErrors** instructs the connection not to throw Http error when it comes across 404, 500, etc error status codes.

> Connection ignoreHttpErrors(boolean ignoreHttpErrors)
>
> Configures the
>   connection to not throw exceptions when a HTTP error occurs. (4xx -
>   5xx, e.g. 404 or 500). By default this is false; an IOException is
>   thrown if an error is encountered. If set to true, the response is
>   populated with the error body, and the status message will reflect the
>   error.
>
> Parameters: ignoreHttpErrors - - false (default) if HTTP errors should
>   be ignored.
>
> Returns: this Connection, for chaining

if you set ignoreHttpErrors to true then you will get the Document. If not then Document will be null.

I also came across this [site](http://oddhour.tumblr.com/post/61615825882/redirect-your-old-tumblr-links-to-your-new) that might actually demonstrate actual tumblr redirect. You might want to use URLs in that page to do your test as they are proper tumblr redirect. If you look inside the retrieved document for this page then you see a JavaScript direct function that triggers after 3 seconds as follow:

```
//redirect to new blog
  setTimeout( redirectTumblr, 3000 );

  function redirectTumblr() {
    location.replace('http://oddhour.tumblr.com' + location.pathname);
  }
```

When I connect to the URL that you have given your in your question. I see 404 page and the content of the 404 page returned in Document by connection contains no sign of redirect (like the other page have).

Comment: Hmmm, actually it seems to work with ignoreHttpErrors,  gives me the redirected url. Thanks!